# How can I get the click event (single, double, long) in react native (expo)?

Tags: react-native, expo, touchableopacity

I am making the button with several click events (single, double, long) in react native.
I have already used the Touchable component and I got these events using a time delay.
But this is not a good solution and there are some issues. it is that when I double-click, the single event has happened concurrently.
In this case, I have to remove the single click event and get the only double click event.
Is there any other good solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Touchable opacity in react native doesn't have the onLongpress or for
>   double click support.

But You can use **[TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback)**, as it supports [onLongPress](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onlongpress) funtionality.

> Furthermore you can just add a custom code for implementing
>   doubleclick in react native touchables.
>  What you can do is to just save the count 
>   on click and
>   clear the click counter after some seconds then trigger a funtion on
>   [onPress](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpress) when it is clicked twice.

**Sample code for doubleclick in react native -**

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, padding: 20, backgroundColor:'green' }}
    onPress={() => {
        this.backCount++
        if (this.backCount == 2) {
            clearTimeout(this.backTimer)
            console.warn("Clicked twice")
        } else {
            this.backTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.backCount = 0
            }, 3000) #mention here the time for clearing the counter in ms
        }

    }}
>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Don't forget to initialize this.backCount = 0 in your constructor

Comment: sound great. would you please provide me an example for me?

Comment: example for which one ? @nikolai-serg

Comment: I mean that getting the double click event example.

Comment: hey @nikolai-serg, i have edited the code, please check it and accept it if it works thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. It's good. then I want to get the click events (single, double, long) by using one component and it is possible with your solution. but your code did not contain this part. (single, long) click. So I updated your answer to matching my question.

Comment: I would added two things to this, first : this.backCount=0 after clearTimeOut  and I would also suggested to add the code inside the setTimeOut for a simple click

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `onPress` & `onLongPress` for single click and long click event. Here is the example you can check:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton} onLongPress={this._onLongPressButton} underlayColor="white">
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Touchable with Long Press</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
```

There is no default behaviour in reactNative/expo to have double click but you can definitely give a look over the modules such as 
1.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-double-tap and 
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-double-click

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have to get these events using a single component. If I use the above library, I can not get the three events on a single component.

Comment: You can check the (1) module. There it has all your three events in it check <DoubleClick
          singleTap={() => {
            console.log("single tap");
          }}
          doubleTap={() => {
            console.log("double tap");
          }}
          delay={200}
        >
           <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        </DoubleClick>

Comment: Good, I will check it.